# Finding error when trying to get the data from API in form of List in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

```
import 'package:basicsforapi/studetDetailModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class newApp extends StatefulWidget {
  newApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _newAppState createState() => _newAppState();
}

class _newAppState extends State<newApp> {
  List<Profile> myallData = [];
  Future<List<Profile>> makeRequest() async {
    var url =
        "http://ec2-232-25-216.ap-suth-1.copte.amoaws.com:124/userdetals?uer=user1";
    var response = await http
        .post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    // print(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    var jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);

    setState(() {
      myallData = jsonBody;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.makeRequest();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hi"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [Text("$myallData")],
        ));
  }
}
```

Json data :

```
[{"ImageUrl":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ff/a0/9a/ffa09aec412db3f54deadf1b3781de2a.png","_id":"5fec7033d5b59b44f5146651","academicYear":2019,"cityId":1,"class":9,"coinBalance":2456,"curr":"CBSE","dob":"20160102","email":"EDTECH001@GMAIL.COM","expPoints":10000,"firstName":"SHAKIBA NAAZ","instituteId":5,"lastName":"EDTECH","mobile":"9999900000","password":"pass1","relatedId":{"id1":"49999"},"studentId":1,"userName":"user1"}]
```

how to handle a list and put all this data separately in the text fields.
even I have seen by making a model even its not getting I am getting this error

ERROR:
Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'.

help me out

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting from api response is not a list of profile object. so you can convert your list of json objects to profile object then asign or save as dynamic list.

Try this.

Change this

```
List<Profile> myallData = [];
```

To this

```
List myallData = [];
```